# View only rows containing 'Foo' from Database in PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two databases. One database contains the products as well as their details. Each product has a specific Stock Number (eg. AG1000). The second database contains comments regarding each product entered by employees (eg. Date of Update, Comments, as well as a column containing the Stock Number of the product).

For the product details page at the bottom I want to populate a table showing all entries in the second database containing the Stock Number of the product details shown.

I've successfully passed the partial view in to the view as well as a placeholder table. But unfortunately, I cannot for the life of me pass the Stock Number to the partial and get the controller/partial to display all rows from Database 2 into the table.

VIEW:

```
@model IdentitySample.Models.InventoryViewModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    string StockNumber = Model.StockNumber;
}



<p class="text-right align-top">@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")</p>
<div class="container">
    <hr />
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header"><h2 class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Year) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Make) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Model) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Trim)</h2></div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col"><img style="width:100%;" src="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PhotoUrl)" /></div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-header"> <h5>Vehicle Details</h5></div>
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <table class="table table-light table-hover table-striped thead-dark">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                       <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StockNumber)</th>
                                                       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StockNumber)</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Year)</th>
                                                      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Year)</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Make)</th>
                                                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Make)</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                       <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Model)</th>
                                                       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Model)</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                       <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Trim)</th>
                                                       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Trim)</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Odometer)</th>
                                                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Odometer)</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
                                    <div class="card-header align-middle"><h5>Vehicle Log<a href="#" class="fa fa-2x fa-plus-square float-right"></a></h5></div>

                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        @Html.Partial("_ViewActions", new List<IdentitySample.Models.InventoryActionsModels>())
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

_Partial:

```
@model IEnumerable<IdentitySample.Models.InventoryActionsModels>

<h5>Test Inventory Action View: @ViewBag.StockNumber</h5>

<table class="table table-light table-hover table-striped thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StockNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TouchType)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TouchedBy)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TouchDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TouchComments)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StockNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TouchType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TouchedBy)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TouchDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TouchComments)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Controller:

```
// GET: InventoryActions
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // ViewBag.StockNumber();
            string vehicleId = StockNumber;
            var vehicle = db.InventoryActionsModels.GroupBy(i => i.StockNumber)
                      .Select(g => new InventoryActionsModels()
                      {
                          StockNumber = vehicleId,
                          Id = g.Max(row => row.Id)
                      }).ToList();

                return View(db.InventoryActionsModels.ToListAsync()); 
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `@ViewBag.StockNumber = Model.StockNumber` after setting the `ViewBag.Title`?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Yes - it seems my issue is coming from the controller. I can't seem to populate the database "pick" criteria from the viewbag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you should create a composite view model for inventory details, and then pass it to your view, kinda

```
public class InventoryDetailsViewModel
{
  public InventoryModel Inventory { get; set; }
  public ICollection<InventoryActionsModels> Actions { get; set; }
}
```

the controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetInventoryDetails(string stockNumber)
{
  var viewModel = new InventoryDetailsViewModel
  {
    Inventory = await GetInventoryById(stockNumber),
    Actions = await GetInventoryActions(stockNumber)
  };
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

where GetInventoryById and GetInventoryActions are methods getting information from databases

then in the view

```
@model IdentitySample.Models.InventoryDetailsViewModel
@Html.Partial("_ViewInventory", Model.Inventory)
@Html.Partial("_ViewActions", Model.Actions)
```

Comment: Perfect - I'm on the right track now. As for the Methods GetInventoryById and GetInventoryActions is it best too call them like so?

`private Task<InventoryViewModels> GetInventoryById(string stockNumber)
        {
            return inventoryViewModels.Where(v => v.StockNumber == stockNumber).FirstOrDefault();
        }`

Comment: @TaylorJones Yes, but in case of asynchronous operation FirstOrDefaultAsync method should be used

Comment: Okay - I'm running in to an error: " 'InventoryViewModels' does not contain a definition for 'Where'. I feel this is an easy fix but I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: @TaylorJones Ough, you have to retrieve it from your DB, like dbContext.InventoryDataSet.Select(x => new InventoryViewModels { here comes mapping }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.StockNumber == stockNumber)